# VS 2019 cannot deploy Sharepoint App - Missing AddSharePointResolver task

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio

We have a Sharepoint App that we have been maintaining & improving for a few years now.  The app is javascript/html code.  I recently (about 3 weeks ago) moved the solution to a new computer and upgraded the solution in VS 2019 and at that time I was able to deploy the App without issue.

Since then I have installed a some Microsoft Version Updates for VS 2019 that I was prompted to install.  The current version of VS 2019 is 16.3.10.  I have also set up the project with version control with a local Git repository and Teams Services.

Now I am not able to deploy the solution due to the following error that occurs when I deploy either the Solution or the App.

The error is as follows:

> The "AddSharePointResolver" task was not found. Check the following:
>
> - 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class.
> - 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface.
> - 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files
>     (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
>     directory.

To this point, to my knowledge, there have not been any "tasks" in the project nor do I know what these actually are.  I cannot find any reference on the internet to "AddSharePointResolver", within the solution, or on the internet.

After some investigating:

- The Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface isnt on my computer
- There are no *.tasks files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin
- I searched for the term "UsingTask" in the solution and it was not found

I'm a bit baffled as to what has changed to prompt for this and what it is actually referring to.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Greg J

Comment: Hi, Did you even figure out what this was?

Comment: Restarting the computer helped me. I should stop working with Microsoft Technologies! SMFH!!

Answer (score 0):

ok so a bit late getting back to this but I did end up resolving the issue.

I reinstalled the Visual C# component, which was the format of the project of the app I was trying to build.